# Why can't pgAdmin III connect to Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I added a new user to posgresql (`amanda`) which is the same as my linux system user. At the console, I can open `psql` just fine -- I don't need a password because I'm already authenticated as `amanda`. When I try to set up pgAdmin III without a password, I get:

```
An error has occurred:

01:18:47 PM: Error: Error connecting to the server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

And if I provide my system password, I get a password error:

```
An error has occurred:

01:15:30 PM: Error: Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "amanda"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "amanda"
```

How do I get pgAdmin3 talking to postgres as `amanda`?

Comment: This question has a home at https://dba.stackexchange.com/. It is not related to programming as such.

Comment: There are plenty of other questions about pgadmin authentication here, though.

Comment: True. But they don't actually belong here. :-) The dba-site has more knowledgeable folks related to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not a real solution but rather a workaround: 
connect as command line and update your password hence:

```
ALTER USER amanda WITH PASSWORD 'your_new_password';
```

Comment: This solution offends me more than it should, because of course it worked. But I shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: @amanda, I totally agree. it's a nasty work-around.
yet, the more I age the more I come to the pragmatic idea that often times solving a problem in 3 minutes in an ugly way is better than spending 5 hours on doing the right thing. especially when the problem is peripheral to what you really want to do. do you really want to to spend your time configuring the users on your dev DB?
chose where to spend your time